# copy pandas background color to pptx-python table

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, python-pptx

I am trying to copy all the `background-color` of cell in a pandas `df` and replicate in the table in python-pptx presentation table:

I have a df that looks something like:

```
colA colB colC
abc  123  bca
xyz  a1a  zya
```

where both the columns colA and colB has different background colors already present in their values (based on some conditions)

Now I have a pptx-python table (exact replica of the original df) but without the background colors. I can iterate over the table like:

```
    for cell in self.iter_cells(table):
        fill = cell.fill
        fill.solid()
        # fill.fore_color.rgb = RGBColor(250, 250, 250)
        # something like this I'm looking to do
        # fill.for_color.rgb = df.iloc[0,0]
```

Comment: You'd need to figure out what method to use to get the background colour of the data frame cell - and might need to convert it to eg RGB. I think the former is where you're stuck.

Comment: @MartinPacker indeed, I am unable to figure that out.